# Is there anyway to view memcache data in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

Basically what I want to do is see the raw data of memcache so that I can see how my data are being stored.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid To get the better understanding of how my/colleagues  data are stored?

Comment: Memcache data is pickled.

Comment: @voscausa Yes, and I am having THE hardest time "unpickling" it. I even tried reading the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for largely the same reasons that [memcached does not support enumerating or dumping the cache](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#How_can_you_list_all_keys?). In order to support such a feature safely, all other cache operations would have to block, which would be unacceptable in a shared environment.

For your purpose of occasionally examining some portion of data in the cache, there is a reasonable alternative. Instrument your (and/or your colleagues) use of the memcache client in order to log which keys are frequently used, then periodically sample those keys' values.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I would have to resort to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the memcache viewer in the admin console?

Comment: I can only view certain keys through the admin console while what I want is to dump the entire data.